# Need to create a gmail like search syntax; maybe using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, search

I need to enhance the search functionality on a page listing user accounts.  Rather than have multiple search boxes for each possible field, or a drop down menu where the user can only search against one field, I'd like a single search box and to use a gmail like syntax.  That's the best way I can describe it, and what I mean by a gmail like search syntax is being able to type the following into the input box:

*username:bbaggins type:admin "made up plc"*

When the form is submitted, the search string should be split into it's separate parts, which will allow me to construct a SQL query.  So for example, *type:admin* would form part of the WHERE clause so that it would find any record where the field *type* is equal to *admin* and the same for *username*.  The text in quotes may be a free text search, but I'm not sure on that yet.

I'm thinking that a regular expression or two would be the best way to do this, but that's something I'm really not good at.  Can anyone help to construct a regular expression which could be used for this purpose?  I've searched around for some pointers but either I don't know what to search for or it's not out there as I couldn't find anything obvious.  Maybe if I understood regular expressions better it would be easier :-)

Cheers,

Adam

Comment: @Matt Ball: If I'd known rep was that easy to get I'd have worked the LotR aspect way harder in my own questions. ;)

Comment: @Robusto: Note to self, my questions need more LotR (so I can upvote me, of course). Perhaps the next SO meme? "-1, needs more balrog"

Comment: @Matt Ball: I was thinking a down-vote would be more like "You ... shall not ... PASS!"

Comment: @All Lotr fans.... Perhaps this question needs more mordor?

Comment: @Robusto: yes, but do you want to be dragged into the depths by a Balrog, only to return years later on Stack Overflow with "the White" added to your nickname and no-one but a couple of silly Hobbits to vote you up again?

Answer (score 1):

No, you would not use regular expressions for this. Just split the string on spaces in whatever language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to use a regex. Regexes are powerful, but in many cases also slow. Regex also [does not handle nested parameters very well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183884/parsing-a-gmail-style-advanced-search-syntax). It would be easier for you to write a script that uses string manipulation to split the string and extract the keywords and the field names.

If you want to experiment with Regex, try the online [REGex tester](http://www.regextester.com/). Find a tutorial and play around, it's fun, and you should quickly be able to produce useful regexes that find any words before or after a `:` character, or any sentences between `"` quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers...I did start doing it without regex and just wondered if a regex would be simpler.  Sounds like it wouldn't though, so I'll go back to the way I was doing it and test it again.

Good old Mr Bilbo is my go to guy for any naming needs :-)

Cheers,

Adam